# Should I allow any URL in order to SSL Certificates be authenticated?

Tags: networking, firewall, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm configuring my company's network.

There are a few different levels of access, which determine what kind of websites the users can access.

The users on the lowest access level should only be able to access a few websites, so I created a white-list containing about 10 URLs, and set the Web Filter to deny connections to any URL that is not on the list.

It works as expected, except for a few websites, like [bizagi.com](http://bizagi.com). When I try to connect to this URL, although it is white-listed, I get the following error:

[image: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN]

The problem is definitely on the Web Filter, because if I change it's default action to Allow sites that are not white-listed, it works as expected.

I understand that I could just add an exception, but it doesn't sound like the right thing to do.

So, my question is: **Should I whitelist any URL in order to SSL certificates be authenticated as expected?** If so, which ones? If not, is there anything else I can do (except adding an exception hehe)?

PS: I'm using Cyberoam CR15ing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your proxy MITM SSL connections? IE, do you have a 'fake' trusted CA on your clients nodes that allow the proxy to function?

Comment: @JasonMartin Yes, it does. The CA is already installed at the clients, in order to the proxy scan HTTPS connections. But, as I said, if I set the default action of the Web Filter to allow connections that are not explicit blocked, it works as expected, even though it is still scanning the connections, which makes me thing the problem is not at the CA. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that the proxy is brokering the SSL connection in some fashion, and is not handling [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) properly. [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.bizagi.com) indicates this website requires SNI, and I've seen this before -- non-SNI clients end up seeing the base certificate, and bizagi is hosted in Azure.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.bizagi.com:443
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.azurewebsites.net
   i:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Microsoft IT/CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Microsoft IT/CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
   i:/C=IE/O=Baltimore/OU=CyberTrust/CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
```

vs

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.bizagi.com:443 -servername www.bizagi.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=GB/ST=Buckinghamshire/L=Gerrards Cross,/O=BIZAGI LIMITED/CN=*.bizagi.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
```

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/1miRz3B3)'s what happens when I run _"openssl s_client -connect www.bizagi.com:443 -servername www.bizagi.com"_

Comment: @appayipyip The fact that the SSL CA returned by that is not the same as outside the network confirms to me your proxy is MITM'ing the connection and not handling SNI properly. You'll have to speak to the proxy vendor about that.

Comment: Hmm, I'll be in touch with them in this case. Just something I'm curious about: what difference does it make, knowing that the problem is with SNI, to blacklist some URLs and allow all the others (which works) or whitelist some URLs and block the others (which causes the problem)?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but the appliance probably doesn't have to MITM all the SSL connections in blacklist-only mode, but does in whitelist mode.  Once it MITMs the connections then it triggers this SNI issue.